# Load html file from my firefox extension's directory

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

**TLDR;** In a Javascript file for my Firefox extension, how can I load the contents of other files from inside my extension (such as an HTML view & CSS stylesheet) for use on the current web-page?

I'm working on my first Firefox extension, for personal use.

So I setup my manifest.json to load `/script/panel.js` when any page of the site loads.

In `panel.js`, I would like to do something like:

```js
const html = MyExtension.getFileContent('/view/panel.html');
const node = document.createElement('div');
node.innerText = html;
document.body.appendChild(node);
```

But I can't find anything like `MyExtension.getFileContent()`. All I've been able to find is how to add sidebar (through manifest?) & browser action for the toolbar at the top of the browser & other non-programmatic ways of exposing files that are inside my extension.

Then in `/view/panel.html`, Ideally, I'd like to also reference `/style/panel.css` which is also found inside my extension's root directory, such as with a `<link` tag.

Comment: See [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you set `web_accessible_resources` in your `manifest.json`? It is required to make resources in your extension readable from webpages.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/web_accessible_resources

Comment: Yeah, I did. It seems like a weird way to access resources, but it got the job done. Just had to figure out how get the url for a resource then make a web request from the content script

Comment: Then `runtime.getURL()` should return the full URL from an internal path, like: `browser.tabs.executeScript(1, { code: "const img = document.createElement('img'); img.src = browser.runtime.getURL('/resources/bookmark-solo.svg'); document.body.appendChild(img); "});`

Comment: Thanks. That `executeScript` function will come in handy.